# Imprimir datos de un foreach con 2 arreglos

Tags: php, php7, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Muy buenas madrugadas Devs, tengo un dilema con el siguiente código. Les doy contexto.

No sé que tan buena práctica sea, pero necesito imprimir desde un `foreach` donde he metido 2 variables, que contienen cada una un arreglo, y le he asignado su respectiva `key` dentro del `foreach`, al momento de hacer `var_dump()` imprime toda la información, pero al querer simplificar o especificar la información que quiero imprimir me arroja un error de índice no definido luego de querer imprimir más allá de colocar `[0]` en la impresión. Adjunto código, mil disculpas que no pueda adjuntar la información dentro de los 2 arreglos.

```php
<?php
    foreach (array($datos2, $dataprograma) as $datosProyecto) : ?>
        <?php echo var_dump($datosProyecto[0]); ?>
<?php endforeach?>
```

Las variables `$datos2` y `$dataprograma` contienen cada una un arreglo al hacer `var_dump()` a solo `$datosProyecto` me imprime todo, al incluir el `[0]` simplifica un poco más la información, pero luego de allí no sé cómo más hacer para imprimir contenido específico de los arreglos, necesito que se haga el `foreach` para poder imprimir los datos dentro de un diseño ya realizado en el sistema.

Agradecería de antemano su ayuda en este tema, espero que se pueda resolver así, de lo contrario acepto sugerencias.

Comment: Si haces `var_export($datos2)` y `var_export($dataprograma)` que te sale?

Comment: Me imprime 3 arreglos 2 con datos casi iguales los cuales comienzan asi

`array ( 0 => array ( 'id_proyecto' => '13', 'titulo_p' =>`

`array ( 0 => array ( 'id_programas' => '21', 'nombre_p' =>`

`array ( 0 => array ( 'id_programas' => '21', 'nombre_p' =>`

Este último tiene menos datos que los 2 primeros.

Comment: No, solo para probar `var_dump($datosProyecto)` y comence a probar con el orden de los arreglos a ver si podía imprimir algo, pero lo único que puedo imprimir o se imprime con el orden de los arrelos es el `[0]['id_proyecto']` de resto ningun otro datos e imprime. incluso usando `[1]['id_proyecto']` se imprime el siguiente id o un id diferente al anterior pero nada más.

Comment: Ambos `array` tienen las mismas `key`?

Comment: Si tal como en el código que coloqué, la key es `$datosProyecto` para todos, lo que no entiendo o encuentro es el por qué solo puedo acceder a un solo dato y el resto aunque se imprimen usando `vard_dump()` no puedo acceder a todos esos otros datos, y disculpa mala mía coloqué el echo en el código que usé en la pregunta  fue inconciente.

Comment: Esque el problema esta en que estas intentando acceder a un `key` que no existe, nose en cual de los `array`... pero al no saber que contiene cada uno, yo no puedo ayudarte... revisa a fondo los dos `array` porque el problema debe de estar ahi... No se cuan largo sera esto, pero hacer un `var_export($datosProyecto)` podria ayudarte...

Comment: Prueba a poner en el `var_dump()` `['id_proyecto']` en vez de `[0]`, a ver si es por esto

Comment: Son super extensos los `var_export()`, adjuntaré un enlace con una captura para que puedas verlo mejor, ya que son un montón de datos.

Array 1: https://prnt.sc/P7Simtoi2ocK
Array 2: https://prnt.sc/XerDTBLO8AJZ
Array 3: https://prnt.sc/tF1j5086Yka1

Comment: Perdona los enlaces se fueron con un "]"  al lado ya los arregle para que si abra la captura de pantalla bien

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138360/discussion-between-adrigo-and-diego-morejon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tras lo comentado en el chat, viendo los datos que tienes, lo que buscas y tu problema, la respuesta a tu pregunta es:

```php
foreach (array($datos2, $dataprograma) as $key => $datosProyecto) :
    echo $dataprograma[$key]['p_indicador'];
```

cambiando la parte de `'p_indicador'` por la que corresponde en cada parte de la tabla: `'p_metas'`, `'p_objetivos'`, etc...

Comment: Muchas gracias de verdad me ayudó muchísimo.